# Can I use CKEDITOR toolbar but the content is locked/readonly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor

my problem is I need to use the toolbar of ckeditor for text style but I need to restrict the user in changing the content.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

To set as read-only, use the CustomConfig method:

```
CKEDITOR.replace(id,{customConfig :readOnly:true});

Example: 
         <textarea id="editor1">Test</textarea>
         CKEDITOR.replace('editor1',{width:'700px',readOnly:true});
```

[Js Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B4yGJ/2/)

Comment: yes. but you can still change text style like making it bold or italic or change font color

Comment: No U can't change text style dude

Comment: I think he wants the user to be able to make them bold or italic but not the user should not be able to change the text.